# how to pass a label value to session variable in c# in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to pass a label value to session variable in c# in asp.net?

The `subtotal` label shows the value but does not pass any value into session variable: `.session["subtotal"]=subtotal.text;`

my code below could you please help #

```html
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteProduct.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Checkout.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ecommerce.Checkout" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <!-- check out -->    
<div class="container">
 <div class="check-sec">  
  <div class="col-md-3 cart-total">
   <a class="continue" href="Default.aspx">Continue to basket</a>
   <div class="price-details">
    <h3>Price Details</h3>
    <span>Total</span>
                <div class="total">
     <span class="simpleCart_total"></span> </div>
   
    <span>Discount</span>
   
                <span class="total1">$00.00</span>
    <span>Delivery Charges</span>
    
                <span class="total1">$00.00(free)</span>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>     
   </div> 
   <ul class="total_price">
      <li class="last_price"> <h4>TOTAL</h4></li> 
      
                <div class="total">
     <span class="simpleCart_total"></span> </div>    
   </ul> 
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <a class="order" href="Checkoutsignin.aspx">Place Order</a>
   
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9 cart-items">
   <h1>My Shopping Bag </h1>

            
             <%--here  cart view start 06/06/2016   --%>
                
        

           
              <table  style="width:100%;"  class="table table-hover">  
                  <ul  >             
             <tr style="width:100%;"   >
                  
               
                 <td style="width:100%;color:red;background-color:lightblue;margin:10px;display:inline-block;padding:18px;" class="simpleCart_items">
                     
                 </td>
             </tr>   
          </ul>   
                 

                  <tr >
    <td>    </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Subtotal</h5></td>
    <td>
       
       <div><asp:Label ID="subtotal" class="simpleCart_total" runat="server"></asp:Label></div>
        
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h5>Estimated shipping</h5></td>
    <td><div class="simpleCart_shipping"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td><h3>Total</h3></td>
    <td>
        <div id="grandtotal" class="simpleCart_grandTotal"></div>

    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
    <td>   </td>
  
    <td><a class="order" href="Checkoutsignin.aspx">FinalCheckout</a></td>
    <td style="visibility:hidden"> <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  </td>
  
    
</tr>

 
  
          </table>         

           
           
                 
             <%-- here cart view end 06/06/2016--%>


           <%-- This part is close start 07/06/2016--%>

     

             <%-- This part is close End 07/06/2016--%>





  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"> </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- //check out -->
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You haven't shown the code where you assign the value to the session and you haven't shown the code where you try to read it.

Comment: Try 
Session["subtotal"]=subtotal.Text;

Comment: where's the code behind?

Comment: I have tried code behind but it show the value  on site but does not control in code behind, please help:                                                                           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {


                
                 Session["subtotal"] = subtotal.Text;


            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
        <asp:Label ID="subtotal" Text="SomeText" class="simpleCart_total" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <%Session["subtotal"] = subtotal.Text; %>
```

Comment: my font end side  show the correct value but code behind does not control this value into session variable please help:                                                                                      <asp:Label ID="subtotal" Text="SomeText" class="simpleCart_total" runat="server"></asp:Label>                                                 <%Session["subtotal"] = subtotal.Text; %>                                                                       my code behind side:  if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                 Session["subtotal"] = subtotal.Text;
            }

Comment: if you want to use Session["subtotal"]  in your server side this is ok.but for ensure that is initial refresh your page for second and look at  Session["subtotal"]  in server side

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I worked this process many times but it's not working my current project . I have tried many ways but still problem..if any solution please let me know.